# When does an assignment do a deep copy in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
store = pd.HDFStore('cache.h5')
data = store['data']
```

In this case, is `data` a deep, in memory copy of the HDF5 data, or is it a pointer to the original data on disk?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *pointer to the original data on disk*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an "in memory object", which will not be reflected (flushed) to disk automatically.

Demo:

```
In [16]: fn = r'D:\temp\.data\test.h5'

In [17]: store = pd.HDFStore(fn)

In [18]: store
Out[18]:
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: D:\temp\.data\test.h5
/df2             frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->7,ncols->4,indexers->[index],dc->[Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4])
/test            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->7,ncols->4,indexers->[index],dc->[Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4])
```

reading from disk (HDF Store) into DataFrame (object in memory):

```
In [19]: data = store['test']

In [20]: data
Out[20]:
        Col1      Col2  Col3  Col4
0       what       the     0     0
1        are    curves     1     8
2        men        of     2    16
3         to      your     3    24
4      rocks      lips     4    32
5        and   rewrite     5    40
6  mountains  history.     6    48

In [21]: data.Col4 = 1000

In [22]: data
Out[22]:
        Col1      Col2  Col3  Col4
0       what       the     0  1000
1        are    curves     1  1000
2        men        of     2  1000
3         to      your     3  1000
4      rocks      lips     4  1000
5        and   rewrite     5  1000
6  mountains  history.     6  1000

In [23]: store.close()

In [24]: store = pd.HDFStore(fn)

In [25]: store['test']
Out[25]:
        Col1      Col2  Col3  Col4
0       what       the     0     0
1        are    curves     1     8
2        men        of     2    16
3         to      your     3    24
4      rocks      lips     4    32
5        and   rewrite     5    40
6  mountains  history.     6    48
```

**UPDATE:** the following small demo shows that the `data` DF does NOT depend on `store` after it's been read up from HDF Store:

```
In [26]: store.close()

In [27]: store = pd.HDFStore(fn)

In [28]: del data

In [29]: data = store['test']
```

let's delete `store` object

```
In [30]: del store
```

`data` is still there

```
In [31]: data
Out[31]:
        Col1      Col2  Col3  Col4
0       what       the     0     0
1        are    curves     1     8
2        men        of     2    16
3         to      your     3    24
4      rocks      lips     4    32
5        and   rewrite     5    40
6  mountains  history.     6    48
```

Comment: Does that mean it's a deep copy? If I read from 'data', am I now reading from RAM or from disk?

Comment: yes, you can consider `data` as a deep copy of one table in the HDF store. Basically it's a DataFrame (object in memory), where `cache.h5` - is HDF (h5) file (on disk), which might contain multiple Tables (DataFrames)

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful!